# WPF popup behavior

Tags: wpf, powershell, popup

I am attempting to adapt [this](https://blog.netnerds.net/2015/09/wpf-popups-lower-right-hand-corner-of-the-screen-notifyicon-powershell/) WPF Popup implementation to implement a messaging system. The goal is a popup any time I need to send a message, and the popup can be closed by the user by double clicking the message, and the message also goes away after a set time.
What I have now is this

```
using assembly PresentationFramework
using assembly System.Windows.Forms
using assembly System.Drawing

$icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$pshome\powershell.exe")
[xml]$xaml =  '<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Name="window" WindowStyle="None" Height="200" Width="400"
ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False">
    <Grid Name="grid" Background="#313130" Height="200" Width="400">
        <Label Name="label" Content="Messanger Test" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Margin="10,10,0,15"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Message" Height = "50" FontSize="18" Margin="10,10,0,15" />
    </Grid>
</Window>'

$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load([System.Xml.XmlNodeReader]::New($xaml))
$window.Left = [System.Windows.SystemParameters]::WorkArea.Width-$window.Width
$window.Top = 0
$message = $Window.FindName('Message')

# Close the window if it's double clicked
$window.Add_MouseDoubleClick({
    $window.Hide()
})

$messageCount = 1
do {
    if ((Get-Random -Minimum:0 -Maximum:100) -le 30) {
        $messageString = "($messageCount) $(Get-Date -format 'HH:mm:ss')"
        $message.Text = $messageString
        Write-Host $messageString
        $messageCount ++
        $window.Show()
        Start-Sleep -s:10
        $window.Hide()
    }

    Start-Sleep -s:5
} while ($messageCount -le 5)
```

This partially works, in that the first message pops up, and it will hide after 10 seconds. However, double clicking to hide doesn't work, nor do subsequent shows happen. I know the criteria are being met, as the console shows each new time message.

So...
What is wrong with my `MouseDoubleClick` event, and
What is keeping messages after the first from showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Start-Sleep` you are using makes the code wait while not processing other events, like the MouseDoubleClick.

In order to have a window keep responding and at the same time wait for a certain period of time, you need to add a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` object.
This Timer has a `Tick` event in which you can stop it from running in order to proceed with the code.

I would suggest something like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon("$pshome\powershell.exe")
[xml]$xaml =  '<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Name="window" WindowStyle="None" Height="200" Width="400"
ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False">
    <Grid Name="grid" Background="#313130" Height="200" Width="400">
        <Label Name="label" Content="Messenger Test" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Margin="10,10,0,15"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Message" Height = "50" FontSize="18" Margin="10,10,0,15" />
    </Grid>
</Window>'

$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load([System.Xml.XmlNodeReader]::New($xaml))
$window.Left = [System.Windows.SystemParameters]::WorkArea.Width-$window.Width
$window.Top = 0
$window.Topmost = $true
$message = $Window.FindName('Message')

# create a Timer object to use instead of Start-Sleep
# old PowerShell: $timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer = [System.Windows.Forms.Timer]::new()
$timer.Add_Tick({
    Write-Host ">> Timer Tick.."
    $timer.Stop()
})

# Close the window if it's double clicked
$window.Add_MouseDoubleClick({
    Write-Host ">> Mouse Double Click.."
    $timer.Stop()
})

$maxLoops = 5
for ($messageCount = 1; $messageCount -le $maxLoops; $messageCount++) {
    $messageString = "($messageCount) $(Get-Date -format 'HH:mm:ss')"
    $message.Text = $messageString
    Write-Host $messageString

    $window.Show()

    # start the timer to fire after 10 seconds and then disable itself
    $timer.Stop()
    $timer.Interval = 10000
    $timer.Start()
    # while the Tick event did not occur, respond to other events
    # such as e mouse double-click on the window
    while ($timer.Enabled) { [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() }

    # the timer tick event happened or the user double-clicked the window
    $window.Hide()

    # end of the loop reached, no use waiting some more..?
    if ($messageCount -ge $maxLoops) { break }

    # start the timer to fire after (random) 1 - 5 seconds
    $interval = (Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5)
    $timer.Stop()
    $timer.Interval = $interval * 1000
    $timer.Start()

    Write-Host ">> Loop wait $interval seconds.."
    while ($timer.Enabled) { [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents() }
} 

# we're done, clean-up
$timer.Dispose()
$window.Close()
```

Comment: Aha! That makes total sense. I can see there may be a lot of PS cmdlets that I need to rethink as I move to WPF & Classes. Lots to learn, and it's only Monday. :)

Comment: So, I have this working on a 2 core VM, but I am seeing something odd. As long as it's processing I am at 50% CPU. I even increased the interval to 10-50 seconds between checks, and still it sits at 50%. At completion or if I kill execution I drop to a base state of 1% pretty much immediately. That seems... wrong. Is there an alternative to the timer that isn't so heavy? I had hoped to run the PS as a background service via Scheduled Task, and check for new messages every 10 seconds or so, but on an Architects workstation I definitely can't be taking an entire core 100% of the time.

Comment: @Gordon That info should have been in the question. The reason for this exercise was never mentioned. For what you want I guess it would be  best to create a [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/may/windows-powershell-writing-windows-services-in-powershell) and have that show the popup, then destroy the window and timer. When needed show the popup again, destroy etc. That way you don't keep everything in memory waiting for a reason to popup.

Comment: I had been trying to keep it simple, figuring learn one thing, then expand. As for a service, so far as I can tell, they only run as System, so a message that the user sees has to be handled differently. But, I have some reading to do with that link tomorrow. I am also looking for changes in a certain key in the LM registry for the message queue, so perhaps I can do something with an event rather than polling on a timer. Lots of variations to try.